# [Geopandas error]fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/3563f91543824520abdaa032ab1a68da' not recognized as a supported file format

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, streamlit, fiona

I wanted to read the `.shp` files by the `file_uploader` of streamlit.

1. Get the list of shp files from the `file_uploader` of streamlit.
2. Read the shp files using the geopandas.

Here's my code.

```py
st.session_state.data_01 = st.file_uploader('Please choose a file.', accept_multiple_files=True, key='0').       
df = []
for d in st.session_state.data_01:
    df.append(gpd.read_file(d),encoding='utf-8')
```

And I got the error such like:

```
  File "/Users/icuh/Desktop/Eun/Web/life.py", line 17, in run_life
    df.append(gpd.read_file(d),encoding='utf-8')
  File "/Users/icuh/opt/anaconda3/envs/impacts_02/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 253, in _read_file
    return _read_file_fiona(
  File "/Users/icuh/opt/anaconda3/envs/impacts_02/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 294, in _read_file_fiona
    with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
  File "/Users/icuh/opt/anaconda3/envs/impacts_02/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 555, in __init__
    super(BytesCollection, self).__init__(self.virtual_file, vsi=filetype, **kwds)
  File "/Users/icuh/opt/anaconda3/envs/impacts_02/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 540, in fiona.ogrext.Session.start
  File "fiona/_shim.pyx", line 90, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/3563f91543824520abdaa032ab1a68da' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Versions I use

- python 3.8.6
- geopandas 0.11.1
- fiona 1.8.21
- shapely 1.8.4

Answer (score 1):

This is not a **streamlit** issue as such.

- have simulated the error you stated with **geopandas** sample shape file
- this fails when shape file has no extension `.shp`.  Same error you reported
- try again with an extension `.shp`.  Different error, partner files missing (`.shx', '.prj', ...)
- try again where all files are in same directory as `.shp`.  Suceeds

Your upload capability needs to take into account that a shape file is a set of files (not a single file).   Either ensure they are all uploaded into same directory.  Alternatively zip them up and upload zip file.  `read_file()` supports zip files.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona
from pathlib import Path
import tempfile
import shutil

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    fn = Path(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
    tmp_file = Path(tmpdirname).joinpath(fn.stem)
    shutil.copy(fn, tmp_file)
    print(tmp_file) # temp file with no extension...
    try:
        gpd.read_file(tmp_file)
    except fiona.errors.DriverError as e:
        print(e)
        tmp_file.unlink()
        # now just the shape file
        tmp_file = Path(tmpdirname).joinpath(fn.name)
        shutil.copy(fn, tmp_file)

        try:
            gpd.read_file(tmp_file)
        
        except fiona.errors.DriverError as e:
            print(e)
            # now all the files that make up an ESRI shapefile
            for fn_ in fn.parent.glob("*"):
                print(fn_.name)
                shutil.copy(fn_, tmpdirname)
            gpd.read_file(tmp_file)
            # no exception :-)
```

#### output

```
/var/folders/3q/trbn3hyn0y91jwvh6gfn7ln40000gn/T/tmpa8x28emo/naturalearth_lowres
'/var/folders/3q/trbn3hyn0y91jwvh6gfn7ln40000gn/T/tmpa8x28emo/naturalearth_lowres' not recognized as a supported file format.
Unable to open /var/folders/3q/trbn3hyn0y91jwvh6gfn7ln40000gn/T/tmpa8x28emo/naturalearth_lowres.shx or /var/folders/3q/trbn3hyn0y91jwvh6gfn7ln40000gn/T/tmpa8x28emo/naturalearth_lowres.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.
naturalearth_lowres.shx
naturalearth_lowres.cpg
naturalearth_lowres.shp
naturalearth_lowres.dbf
naturalearth_lowres.prj
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answering. I tried this, but it didn't work. The geopandas can read the `shp` files without other optional files. I checked the file uploader read the shp file for the **bytes**. I think need to convert the files from the bytes to shp format(such as string).